# List all files under different folders with same name

Tags: files, ls

I have different folders with the name "templates" in various locations in my code. I need to list all the files within the folders with the name "templates"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will find all the directories with the name "templates" beneath the current directory and list all the files in them

```
find -name 'templates' -type d -execdir ls {} \;
```

Comment: Awesome this work great. But sometimes I have other folders within the templates folder as well. In such scenarios I want to do this recursively. Is that something that is possible?

Comment: Try this `find -name 'templates' -type d -execdir find {} \;`

Answer (score 3):

All files within `templates` folders, recursively:

```
find . -path '*/templates/*'
```

If you don't want the files in the subdirectories of `templates` folders (except for the `templates/foo/templates/bar` ones for course), you could use the `-regex` extension of some `find` implementations:

```
find . -regex '.*/templates/[^/]*'
```

If you only want *regular* files, add a `-type f`. For any type of files except directory, `! -type d`.

If you only care for the files' names and not the path leading to them, with GNU `find`, add a `-printf '%f\n'` (and maybe pipe to `sort -u`, assuming the file names don't contain newline characters, to get unique names).